# numpy.arange strage behaviour

Tags: arrays, numpy, range

Working with arange of numpy

```
In [22]: np.arange(0.95,0.98,0.01)
Out[22]: array([ 0.95,  0.96,  0.97,  0.98])
```

as I expected. But, when I do

```
In [23]: np.arange(0.9,1.2,0.1)
Out[23]: array([ 0.9,  1. ,  1.1])
```

I thought that it must do:

```
Out[23]: array([ 0.9,  1. ,  1.1, 1.2])
```

Can anyone explain to me why?

Info: Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 05:13:16) and 
Numpy 1.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the weird behavior is what you expected. From the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

> `numpy.arange([start], stop[, step], dtype=None)`
>
> Return evenly spaced values within a given interval.
>
> Values are generated within the half-open interval [start, stop) (in
>   other words, the interval including start but excluding stop).
>
> When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not
>   be consistent. It is better to use linspace for these cases.

You are probably being hit by some floating point rounding error:

```
>>> (0.98-0.95) / 0.01
3.0000000000000027
>>> (1.2-0.9) / 0.1
2.999999999999999
```

The number of items in the array is of course that number rounded up, so the first case will (wrongly) include the endpoint, while the second will (correctly) not. As the docs suggest, take a look at [`np.linspace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are right. I just looking for this behaviour, I founded another way to solve using round, numpy.array and range but I'll use np.linspace